# Hibernate 5.x + Spring 5.x, can't autowire SessionFactory in DAOImpl class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, autowired, sessionfactory

I'm writing a very simplistic crm web app and I've got a problem with autowiring hibernate sessionFactory bean in one of my DAO classes. I've been searching internet for couple days now and I'm quite confused, cause my config seems to mirror those that are said to be working on the net. In this project I don't use xml's.

**web servlet config class**

```
public class WebServletConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer
{

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
{
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webContext.register(SpringConfig.class);
    webContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webContext));
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/");
}
}
```

**spring config class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.crmproject")
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer 
{

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver()
{
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource()
{
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("resources/messages");

    return messageSource;
}

public void configureDefaultSevletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer)
{
    configurer.enable();
}

}
```

**hibernate config file**

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig
{

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
{
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.crmproject.entity");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource()
{
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
    dataSource.setUsername("hbstudent");
    dataSource.setPassword("hbstudent");

    return dataSource;
}

private final Properties hibernateProperties()
{
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

    return hibernateProperties;
}

}
```

And I'm trying to autowire sessionFactory in this DAO class, but when I call `testMethod` to see if sessionFactory have been injected, it throws `NullPointerException`.

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO
{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public void testMethod()
{
    System.out.println(sessionFactory.toString());
}

public CustomerDAOImpl()
{
    System.out.println("in CustomerDAOImpl constructor");
}

public List<Customer> getCustomers()
{
    return null;
}

public Integer saveCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    return null;
}

public Customer getCustomer(Integer id)
{
    return null;
}

public boolean updateCustomer(Integer id, Customer customer)
{
    return false;
}

public boolean deleteCustomer(Integer id)
{
    return false;
}
}
```

**exception:**

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with
>   path [/crm2-project] threw exception [Request processing failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.crmproject.dao.CustomerDAOImpl.testMethod(CustomerDAOImpl.java:26)
>     at
>   com.crmproject.controller.CustomerController.listCustomers(CustomerController.java:31)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Why isn't Spring injecting sessionFactory bean?

edit:
Adding controller code per request

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController
{

@RequestMapping("/customerAddForm")
public String showAddCustomerForm(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
    System.out.println("Inside showAddCustomerForm method");
    return "customer-add-form";
}

@RequestMapping("/list")
public String listCustomers(Model model)
{
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    new CustomerDAOImpl().testMethod();
    model.addAllAttributes(customers);

    return "list-customers";
}

@RequestMapping("/proccessAddForm")
public void proccessAddForm(@ModelAttribute("customer")Customer customer)
{
    System.out.println("Inside proccessAddForm method, customer: " + customer.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to set sessionFactory again using setter?                          
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
} Please remove this code and check once more.

Comment: @AbhayJain I removed setter code but nothing changed. Still NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you post complete stacktrace in proper format if its  there?

Comment: @AbhayJain Sorry for the formatting, I'm aware that I could have done a better job but it's my first post so far. It's the full stack trace that I have. Application is deployed on tomcat. I access url which is mapped to method that also calls mentioned testMethod() from CustomerDAOImpl class. Then I get http 500 error in the browser and stacktrace pointing at NullPointerException at line 20 of dao class. So it is clear that sessionFactory object is null at that time and the dependency hasn't been satisfied by spring. Not sure what else info I can provide.

Comment: Check this. http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring.

Comment: @AbhayJain Thanks but I've been there already couple days ago, my config seems to be nearly the same and still I got the error.

Comment: I think I missed transaction manager bean in the your hibernate config file. Can you check once?

Comment: Can you post the code for CustomerController?

Comment: @AbhayJain I already tried config with EnableTransactionManagement annotation and the bean configured and also without it. The results were the same.

Comment: @StefanEmanuelsson Edited the original post and posted controller code. I think I know what's happening, I'll try to autowire the DAOImpl class object inside CustomerController. Maybe simply creating DAO class with "new" keyword is not enough or ok from Spring point of view.

Comment: That was what i suspected. Good you found it yourself, always more pleasing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my Controller class. I tried to create the CustomerDAOImpl object using "new CustomerDAOImpl().testMethod();". Spring obviously didn't like it. I changed it to 
"@Autowired
CustomerDAOImpl customerDAOImpl;" and now it's working, NullPointerException is gone. What a dumb mistake but at the same time, great learning experience. Thanks for help!

Comment: When you create class instance using constructor, Spring doesnt know about this class and can not set their dependancy or use this class for dependency.

Comment: Happy coding :)